# Image Mapping with a CENTERED image

Tags: css, image

I am using an image with several hot spots for navigation:
http://hospicehub.com/

The problem is that the image is aligned left and not horizontally centered.
I've tried background-position: 50% 0
I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a 
I've tried adding margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

Nothing seems to have any effect???

Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.map_image { display: block; width: 816px; height: 666px; position: relative; background-position: 0 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.map_image .map_link { display: block; position: absolute; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; }
.map_image #map_link_0 { width: 306px; height: 35px; top: 241px; left: 489px; }
.map_image #map_link_1 { width: 305px; height: 35px; top: 289px; left: 490px; }
.map_image #map_link_2 { width: 305px; height: 38px; top: 336px; left: 491px; }
.map_image #map_link_3 { width: 302px; height: 38px; top: 384px; left: 493px; }
.map_image #map_link_4 { width: 301px; height: 37px; top: 434px; left: 493px; }
.map_image #map_link_5 { width: 299px; height: 39px; top: 482px; left: 494px; }
.map_image #map_link_6 { width: 298px; height: 36px; top: 533px; left: 495px; }
.map_image #map_link_7 { width: 300px; height: 38px; top: 581px; left: 495px; }
</style>

<div class="map_image" style="background-image: url('/images/home-nav2.png');">
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_0" title="" href="/hospices"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_1" title="" href="/pbm"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_2" title="" href="/pharmacies"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_3" title="" href="/medicare-part-d"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_4" title="" href="/emr"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_5" title="" href="/dme"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_6" title="" href="/medical-supply"></a>
<a class="map_link" id="map_link_7" title="" href="/cms"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are just doing image mapping, why not use the proper [`map` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).  I see no benefit in doing it with css

Comment: I tried using straight HTML, but was really wonkie. The hotspots, while spanning the full width of the boxes in the graphic, were only active about half the width necessary. Revealing the boxes with developer tools plugins showed the outlines being the correct size, but they just wouldnt work. It was very strange.